# NodeJS, return from callback in callback in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am having issues getting the value returned from a function nested in a function from another function. The code is pretty complicated, but i mocked up something here:

```
var request = require('request');
var _url = 'test.com/data/data.json';

function getValue() {
  var val = 0;
  return callFromURL(function(result){
    if(result) {
      // Do stuff...

      console.log(result); //Returns a value
      return result;
    }
  })
}

function callFromURL(callback) {
  request(_url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var service = JSON.parse(body);
            return callback(service);
        } else {
            log.error(error);
            return callback(null);
        }
    });
}


function test() {
  getValue(); //returns undefined
}
```

When i step through using a debugger or `console.log` statements I see that the inner return in the callback passed to callFromURL is not undefined, but the result of `return callbackFromURL` is `undefined`. How can I correctly return `result` from the `getValue()` function in this example?

Comment: See classic async question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: yeah you can't do that.

Comment: Your saying it isn't possible to get result to return in the main function? I have a hard time believing that

Comment: Yup, not possible. Once you go async there is no way out. The approach is to nest callbacks or pass promises around. It was never possible for a function to return to the outer function.

Comment: What you're asking for is similar to asking to be able to return a value from an ajax call to the function that initiated the ajax call; it simply isn't possible unless you make the ajax request synchronous.

Comment: @PepperedLemons: The function returns before the callback is executed asynchronously. Unless you invent time travel, it's impossible to get a value from the callback as the return value of the function.

Comment: Makes sense after reading the other post. Thanks for the help everyone!